# List Value to XML conversion using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have data in this format in a list

```
ItemA   LoaderA ConfigA 30
ItemA   LoaderA ConfigB Default=180
ItemA   LoaderA ConfigC 20

ItemB   LoaderA ConfigA 30
ItemB   LoaderA ConfigB Default=120
ItemB   LoaderA ConfigC 30

ItemC   LoaderB ConfigD 30
ItemC   LoaderB ConfigE Default=120
ItemC   LoaderB ConfigF 10

ItemA   LoaderB ConfigD 30
ItemA   LoaderB ConfigE Default=30
ItemA   LoaderB ConfigF 10
```

I am trying to use LINQ to group the data via ApplicationName (loaderA and B in this case)
And then would need to group by ProductName (ItemA,ItemB and ItemC) using the data obtained I need to generate an XML document 
in below format

```
<Application Name=LoaderA>
  <Product Name=ItemA>
    <Config Name=ConfigA>30</Config>
    <Config Name=ConfigB>Default=180</Config>
    <Config Name=ConfigC>20</Config>
  </Product>
  <Product Name=ItemB>
    <Config Name=ConfigA>30</Config>
    <Config Name=ConfigB>Default=120</Config>
    <Config Name=ConfigC>30</Config>
  </Product>
</Application>
<Application Name=LoaderB>
  <Product Name=ItemC>
    <Config Name=ConfigD>30</Config>
    <Config Name=ConfigE>Default=120</Config>
    <Config Name=ConfigF>20</Config>
  </Product>
  <Product Name=ItemA>
    <Config Name=ConfigD>30</Config>
    <Config Name=ConfigE>Default=120</Config>
    <Config Name=ConfigF>30</Config>
  </Product>
</Application>
```

Can someone please share as to how should I group by items so I leverage using XElement class to create XML in the format described above.

Comment: What is the source for the list?  Is it in memory (list of lists), text file, etc?  Also, your XML is not valid - you need a root element that is not repeated.

Comment: The source of the data is from a text file. And I apologize for missing the root element.

Comment: Is that the exact format of the file?  It looks like it's space-delimited.

Comment: its Tab delimited. (4 columns are separated by Tab)

Comment: Do you want to convert the file into an intermediate object and then use that object to generate the XML, or take the file and generate XML directly from it?

Comment: @Tim: I am trying to learn LINQ, therefore I thought lets see if LINQ can help here. But open to others suggestion as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you're learning LINQ, so I used LINQ more than I would normally do.
This produces xml exactly like yours, with the exception of attributes being surrounded by quotation marks.

```
class ListFileToXmlConverter
{
    private class Entry
    {
        public string Application { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public string Config { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Entry> LoadEntries(string filename)
    {
        return File.ReadAllLines(filename)
            .Where(line => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            .Select(line => line.Split(new[] {'\t'}))
            .Select(split => new Entry
                {
                    Product = split[0],
                    Application = split[1],
                    Config = split[2],
                    Value = split[3]
                });
    }

    public XElement ConvertToXml(string filename)
    {
        return new XElement("root",
            LoadEntries(filename)
                .GroupBy(entry => entry.Application)
                .Select(grouping =>
                    new XElement(
                        "Application",
                        new XAttribute("Name", grouping.Key),
                        grouping
                            .GroupBy(entry => entry.Product)
                            .Select(grouping2 =>
                                new XElement(
                                    "Product",
                                    new XAttribute("Name", grouping2.Key),
                                    grouping2.Select(entry =>
                                        new XElement("Config",
                                            new XAttribute("Name", entry.Config),
                                            entry.Value)
                                        )
                                    )
                            )
                        )
                )
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. Really appreciate your input here.